# Issue When too many open files

Tags: c++, root-framework

`I have multiple input root files (150 files)from different directories, and I intend to incorporate all of them into my code. However, when I run the code, it seems to only process the last file, even though I have tested it with just two files. Strangely, I'm not encountering any error messages.

Additionally, I'm facing another issue. When I open a new TBrowser, I find that I can't access my histograms. Below is a section of my code (header file)for reference:`

```
class inclphoton {
public:
    TTree *fChain;
    Int_t fCurrent;

    vector<float> *ttdata_presel_photonPt;

    TBranch *b_ttdata_presel_photonPt;
    std::vector<std::string> files;
    inclphoton(TTree *tree = nullptr);
    virtual ~inclphoton();
    virtual Int_t Cut(Long64_t entry);
    virtual Int_t GetEntry(Long64_t entry);
    virtual Long64_t LoadTree(Long64_t entry);
    virtual void Init(TTree *tree);
    virtual void Loop();
    virtual Bool_t Notify();
    virtual void Show(Long64_t entry = -1);
};

#endif
#ifdef inclphoton_cxx
inclphoton::inclphoton(TTree *tree) : fChain(0)
{
    TH1::AddDirectory(kFALSE);
files.push_back("/userdata/incPhoton/data15/user.data15periodd.n181.periodD.DAOD_STDM2.grp23_v01_p3984_ANALYSIS_ntuples/user.26552633._000001.ANALYSIS.root");
files.push_back("/userdata/incPhoton/data15/user..data15periodd.n181.periodD.DAOD_STDM2.grp23_v01_p3984_ANALYSIS_ntuples/user.26552633._000002.ANALYSIS.root");
//files.push_back("/userdata/incPhoton/data15/user..data15periodd.n181.periodD.DAOD_STDM2.grp23_v01_p3984_ANALYSIS_ntuples/user.26552633._000003.ANALYSIS.root");
    if (!tree) {
        TFile *f;
 
        for (const auto& fileName : files) {
           std::cout << "Processing file: " << fileName << std::endl;
           f = TFile::Open(fileName.c_str());
            if (!f || !f->IsOpen()) {
                std::cerr << "Error opening file: " << fileName << std::endl;
                continue;
            }      
            f->ls(); 
            f->GetObject("analysis", tree);
            std::cout<< "////////////////////////////////////////////"<<std::endl;
            std::cout << "Total entries in fChain: " << tree->GetEntries() << std::endl;

        }
    }
    Init(tree);
}


inclphoton::~inclphoton()
{
    if (!fChain) return;
    delete fChain->GetCurrentFile();
}

Int_t inclphoton::GetEntry(Long64_t entry)
{
    if (!fChain) return 0;
    return fChain->GetEntry(entry);
}

Long64_t inclphoton::LoadTree(Long64_t entry)
{
    if (!fChain) return -5;
    Long64_t centry = fChain->LoadTree(entry);
    if (centry < 0) return centry;
    if (fChain->GetTreeNumber() != fCurrent) {
        fCurrent = fChain->GetTreeNumber();
        Notify();
    }
    return centry;
}

void inclphoton::Init(TTree *tree)
{
    ttdata_presel_photonPt = 0;
    if (!tree) return;
    fChain = tree;
    fCurrent = -1;
    fChain->SetMakeClass(1);
    fChain->SetBranchAddress("ttdata_presel_photonPt", &ttdata_presel_photonPt, &b_ttdata_presel_photonPt);
    Notify();
}

Bool_t inclphoton::Notify()
{
    return kTRUE;
}

void inclphoton::Show(Long64_t entry)
{
    if (!fChain) return;
    fChain->Show(entry);
}

Int_t inclphoton::Cut(Long64_t entry)
{
    return 1;
}
#endif
```

`I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on resolving these issues. Thank you!`

Comment: If `f->GetObject("analysis", tree);` replaces the contents of `tree`, it only contains the data from the last iteration.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! Could you kindly provide guidance on which alternative instruction I should use instead?

Comment: That depends how you want to handle all those open files. You could, for example, load each file into a separate `TTree` object?

Comment: I have no idea what `TFile` and `TTree` are, so it's impossible to say what you should do instead. If you want to merge all the data into one tree, there might be something in `TTree` that does it, or you may have to write that code yourself.

Comment: I have several files (150) input root files and I don’t think this is relevant for loading each file into separate `TTree` , and I want to loop for over the data to extract the variables on the `TTree`,

Comment: @molbdnilo I use **TFile** to open each root file and all the file contain  **Ttree**  that named analysis and I want to loop over these files

Comment: @Sandra Yes, that's what your code says, but what should the result of the loop be? Do you want each tree to be part of the "chain"? Perhaps [this](https://root.cern/manual/trees/#appending-ttrees-as-a-tchain) is what you're looking for?

Comment: @molbdnilo My resultl will be draw some variables found in Ttree and draw them in histograms, Knowing that all the Ttree in each file contain the same name please find below my part of my source code:

Comment: `for (Long64_t i=0; i<nentries;i++) {
      Long64_t ientry = LoadTree(i);
      if (ientry < 0) break;
      nb = fChain->GetEntry(i);   nbytes += nb;
      float highPt = 0.0;
      int nPtBins = 12; // 13 - 1
      int ipps = ttdata_presel_photonPt->size();
      //      tdata_HLT_g140_loose = false;
      for ( int ipp = 0; ipp<ipps; ipp++ )
        {
         pt=ttdata_presel_photonPt->at(ipp);
        eta= ttdata_presel_photonEta->at(ipp);
         if (pt > 250){
            if (fabs(eta)<=0.6) {
                ptHistogram_1A->Fill(pt);
            }`

Comment: Thank you very much @molbdnilo , the problem is fixed following this link : https://root.cern/manual/trees/#appending-ttrees-as-a-tchain

Comment: You could also possibly merge all 150 root files beforehand into a single one with [hadd](https://root.cern/manual/root_files/#merging-root-files-with-hadd).